# How to configure build.gradle so that my project gets build in tomcat webapps?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, gradle

I'm new to gradle and I'm not able to configure the build.gradle to deploy my project directly from eclipse to tomcat webapps.
Can anyone please suggest how i can do this or provide some references where i can learn this.
Regards

Comment: I'm not sure if there is currently a solution for this that works out-of-the-box. Have you applied the `eclipse-wtp` plugin and checked the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin to deploy your web application to Tomcat, see https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin. There is also a Gradle build-in plugin to directly run your webapp within Jetty from command line, see http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/jetty_plugin.html.